# Empty mail with Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, maven, email

i'm trying to send a simple email using Spring framework but i have a very strange problem: everything is working fine in Junit test case, but when i call the function from the application, the mail has correct recipients but it's empty! (in Gmail i can see a "no name" attachment).

Here my configuration:

**MailerServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public void sendMail(String recipient, String content,
        String attachmentFileName, byte[] attachment) throws Exception {

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();


    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setFrom(simpleMailMessage.getFrom());
    helper.setTo(recipient);
    helper.setSubject(simpleMailMessage.getSubject());
    helper.setText(String.format(simpleMailMessage.getText(), content));

    if (attachment != null && attachmentFileName != null) {
        helper.addAttachment(attachmentFileName, new ByteArrayResource(
                attachment));
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "MimeMessageHelper Created");
    try {
        mailSender.send(message);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Email sent to: "
                + message.getAllRecipients().toString());
    } catch (MailException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while sending mail", e);
        throw new EipException("Errore email", e);
    }

}
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;

public void setSimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {
    this.simpleMailMessage = simpleMailMessage;
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="192.168.209.208" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="simpleMailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="info@test.com" />
    <property name="to" value="" />
    <property name="subject" value="Info" />
    <property name="text">
        <value><![CDATA[%s]]></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Test Case**

```
public class TaskServiceTest extends AbstractApplicationContextTest {

@Autowired 
MailerService mailerService;

@Test
public void testMail(){

    String testoEmail = "test mail";


    String[] indirizzi = {"xxx@example.com"};

    try {
        mailerService.sendMail(indirizzi, testoEmail, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }

}
```

}

In Junit test case i load the same spring context, the only difference in the webapp is the database configuration (via JNDI in Tomcat)... but this shouldn't be the issue..

I thought about a library conflict in Maven (i read about a conflict with geronimo-mail)... but seems to be working fine 
Any suggestion?

Bye
Carlo

### Edit:

these are two logs of two sent emails. (the former is the blank one, the latter is the correct one)

**blank**

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "192.168.209.208", port 25,     isSSL false
220 hostname ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "192.168.209.208", port: 25

EHLO MASLNN112
250-hostname
250-PIPELINING 
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxx@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<xxx@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xxx@example.com
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 11:49:21 +0100 (CET)
From: xxx@example.com
To: xxx@example.com
Message-ID: <839107267.2.1455619761727.JavaMail.carlo@MASLNN112>
Subject: Integrazione Enel - Comunicazione
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_1452882369.1455619761619"

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AB2047A5251
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

**correct**

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "192.168.209.208", port 25, isSSL false
220 hostname ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "192.168.209.208", port: 25

EHLO MASLNN112
250-hostname
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxx@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<xxx@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xxx@example.com
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 11:45:51 +0100 (CET)
From: xxx@example.com
To: xxx@example.com
Message-ID: <563330706.2.1455619551945.JavaMail.carlo@MASLNN112>
Subject: Integrazione Enel - Comunicazione
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_967231573.1455619550687"

------=_Part_0_967231573.1455619550687
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
boundary="----=_Part_1_309604348.1455619550701"

------=_Part_1_309604348.1455619550701
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test mail.
------=_Part_1_309604348.1455619550701--

------=_Part_0_967231573.1455619550687--
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as DFC317A5251
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

**Edit 2:**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.arpav</groupId>
<artifactId>eip2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Enel Integrator Process 2</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <drools.version>6.2.0.Final</drools.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.core.version>4.2.6.Final</hibernate.core.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <jboss.javaee.version>1.0.0.Final</jboss.javaee.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.9</logback.version>
    <h2.version>1.3.161</h2.version>
    <btm.version>2.1.4</btm.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <sitemesh.version>3.0.0</sitemesh.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.9</jackson.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>


    <!-- test dependencies -->

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.btm</groupId>
        <artifactId>btm</artifactId>
        <version>${btm.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet & Jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Sitemesh -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>${sitemesh.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0-4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Richieste http -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SDEE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.enel</groupId>
        <artifactId>SDEE</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Invio emails -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- <repository> <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id> <name>JBoss Public 
        Repository Group</name> <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url> 
        <releases> <enabled>true</enabled> <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy> </releases> 
        <snapshots> <enabled>true</enabled> <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy> </snapshots> 
        </repository> -->
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>eip2</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: yes Rai, i add an Edit

Comment: What does your application return if you print out the value of `simpleMailMessage.getText()` and `content` in your `sendMail()` method?  (Or, you can launch your debugger and look)

Comment: @bphilipnyc `simpleMailMessage.getText()` return `%s` and `content` return the correct text of the email.

Comment: if you try `setText("some gibberish", true)` instead, do you get `some gibberish` as the content while running the application?  Just trying to isolate.

Comment: Also, is your message subject working?  I'm thinking you may have edited it since the output doesn't match the bean, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if i try `setText("some gibberish", true)` i don't get `some gibberish`, but instead the original text passed to the function `sendMail`.

Comment: My message subject is correctly working..

Comment: Seems that calling MimeMessageHelper setter `setText` doesn't change the content of MimeMessage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104189/discussion-between-carlessa-and-bphilipnyc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
In my pom.xml i added the `provided` scope for javax.mail dependency, like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <------------ here
    </dependency>
```

i don't know exactly why in test environment everything was working but from [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) about dependency scopes this is the explanation:

> provided:
>   This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Maybe there was a conflict between classes in classpath in runtime environment.

Thanks to @bphilipnyc and @Rai for their hints.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the default encoding to `UTF-8` since it is not clear what the default is between your unit test and the application:

```
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
```

My guess is that it may vary between your test and the application runtime judging by the call made by `MimeMessageHelper`. In this case, `MimeMessage` is a `SmartMimeMessage` as specified within `JavaMailSenderImpl` on `MimeMessage` creation:

```
/**
 * This implementation creates a SmartMimeMessage, holding the specified
 * default encoding and default FileTypeMap. This special defaults-carrying
 * message will be autodetected by {@link MimeMessageHelper}, which will use
 * the carried encoding and FileTypeMap unless explicitly overridden.
 * @see #setDefaultEncoding
 * @see #setDefaultFileTypeMap
 */
public MimeMessage createMimeMessage() {
    return new SmartMimeMessage(getSession(), getDefaultEncoding(), getDefaultFileTypeMap());
}
```

Default encoding is determined from `SmartMimeMessage`:

```
protected String getDefaultEncoding(MimeMessage mimeMessage) {
    if (mimeMessage instanceof SmartMimeMessage) {
        return ((SmartMimeMessage) mimeMessage).getDefaultEncoding();
    }
    return null;
}
```

From the `SmartMimeMessage` JavaDoc:

> Special subclass of the standard JavaMail MimeMessage, carrying a
>   default encoding to be used when populating the message and a default
>   Java Activation FileTypeMap to be used for resolving attachment types.
>
> Created by JavaMailSenderImpl in case of a specified default encoding
>   and/or default FileTypeMap. Autodetected by MimeMessageHelper, which
>   will use the carried encoding and FileTypeMap unless explicitly
>   overridden.

Comment: Rai, thank you for your answer but this is not resolving the problem. I tried to specify the encoding as you suggested me and debugging i saw the encoding field of MimeMessageHelper object correctly populated... so this is not the issue. Furthermore i noticed that if i don't declare the encoding in both test environtment and runtime environment the field is not populated...i think in this problem the encoding is irrilevant..

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. What I would do next is try to eliminate as many dependencies as possible in Maven (one by one). Also, try to inline the data in your `simpleMailMessage` just to see if that makes a difference.